# Recovering Python file that is deleted yet still visible

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, spyder, recovery

The other night I was running a Python script that was calculating a simulation which I left to run overnight. I came back the next day to find that the interpreter (Spyder) has been closed and the script not only hadn't finished, but proceeded to get deleted in the process. The file name and path were still in the history, but when I tried to execute it again, I got an error that the script no longer exists. Searching for the file in the deleted items and the original folder yielded mostly nothing. I was able to find a trace of the file, called `DMEmodel.py`, when I searched from Ubuntu's taskbar.

The file popped up, but instead of having a Python related icon, it had a web icon associated with it. Clicking on it showed the file path, `http://DMEmodel.py`, but the path didn't make any sense. Further, the search also turned up the folder which the original file was located in, `/home/user1`. The path name for the original file was `/home/user1/DMEmodel.py`.

My session of Chrome was similarly closed, but `CONTROL + SHIFT + T`, got my session back. This makes me think that a power outage might have caused the file deletion during the simulation. Any suggestions on how I can recover the file? Is it possible to recover

I am running Ubuntu 16, Spyder 2.3.8 and Python 2.7.11.

Comment: More than a python problem this seems a filesystem problem. I believe your question is more appropriate for SuperUser. Consider booting from a liveCD and using something like gparted to check whether the filesystem is ok (it has options to do so). There also other tool available for filesystem recovery, but it depends on the damage it was done.  Also: consider using a journalling file system (e.g. ext3/ext4 **not** ext2) which are much more robust against such failures.

Comment: Since you are running Ubuntu, I would suggest asking on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).